# Meteor mup setup don't work

Tags: meteor

I would like use Meteor Up for deploy my app on my Digital Ocean server.

I've init with `mup init` and config my `mup.js`. When i run `mup setup`, it just open my mup.js on my editor ..

Do you have any idea why the file is opened and not config my server ?

THank you !

Comment: if you installed by default with npm global please try with `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mupx/bin/mup setup`

Comment: Sorry Gemmi, i'm on Windows ^^

Comment: Here my knowledge ends :D

Answer (score 3):

Problem is the mup.js has an association with a program, instead of typing mup use

```
mup.cmd
```

eg

```
   mup.cmd setup
   mup.cmd deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where my command line would not run the mup commands. I finally found a solution where I used windows PowerShell.

Just click the Windows Start button and search PowerShell, run it and use the commands just like you would in a regular command prompt.